# Exit navigationItem by swiping anywhere on the screen does not work as expected when returning from non navigation controller viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift

I add the following code to every VCTest:

```
    let popGestureRecognizer = self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!
    if let targets = popGestureRecognizer.value(forKey: "targets") as? NSMutableArray {
      let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
      gestureRecognizer.setValue(targets, forKey: "targets")
      self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
```

This allows me to swipe from anywhere on the screen back to the base viewcontroller (child of navigation controller) from anywhere on the screen.

When however I leave to a non-navigationcontroller controller, and then return, swiping on the screen all of a sudden does not work. Litteraly nothing is interactable.

**Why is this happening and how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

`interactivePopGestureRecognizer` docs:

> The navigation controller installs this gesture recognizer on its view and uses it to pop the topmost view controller off the navigation stack

So basically this works only for `ViewControllers` inside of `UINavigationController` stack. What you can do is create another `panGestureRecognizer` for non-navigation controllers:

```
let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

@objc
func dismissController() {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I think this answer belives that the issue is that I am unable to swipe back, this is wrong. The issue is that After leaving (by pressing a cancel button) nothing is interactible.

Comment: Did you try visual debugger? Maybe there is not dismissed view which is blocking interaction